# How to make a form with multiple items from database with laravel

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I have taken a list of items from a table in my DB , now I want to make a form that consists of a dropdown box containing all these items. And when I click an item I want it to be added to a list next to the listbox so I can save these multiple items in my db . (The main goal is to select a single or multiple labels for a newsitem in my site)

code in html that gives list of labels (working) :

```
 @foreach($labels as $label)

            <p>{{$label}}</p>

 @endforeach
```

Now I need a {{Form:: ......   element that creates a dropdown box of all these labels.

Comment: Just surround the foreach with `<select>` ... and `</select>` and change the `<p>` to `<option>{{$label}}</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a jquery plugin :

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

and this code :

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <select name="labels[]" class="form-control chosen-select-video" data-placeholder="Add labels..." multiple >
               @foreach ($labels as $title)
                   <option value="{{$title}}">{{ucfirst($title)}}</option>  <!-- Capitalize first letter -->
               @endforeach
         </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a dropdown list in laravel you can use-

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'));
```

here `array` is your list taken from database. you can find details about laravel form helper in this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists). and for showing a list of selected item next to your dropdownlist you should use javascript or jQuery.